# Can Javascript callbacks cause stack overflow?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I am trying to do event-driven GUI in Javascript.

Since this involves a lot of callbacks, I was wondering if it is a good design to do something like this (I've marked irrelevant code with triple dot):

```
function flipToPage(num) {
    [...]
    setupPage(..., function() {
       flipToPage(num+1)
    }
}

function setupPage(..., readyCallBack) {
    var num = Object.keys(drawables).length;
    for (drawable in drawables) {
        drawable.draw(..., function() {
            if (--num <= 0) {
                readyCallBack();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I am wondering if the above would cause a stackoverflow at some point, considering it is an unlimited recursion of events stacking on top of each other in the end.

Comment: A related question: would it make sense to put a bogus `setTimeout(..., 1)` call to break the infinite loop mentioned above?

Comment: Put a break point and see if stack grows infinitely. If it does - then it may cause stack overflow.